# Creating multiple results from Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a fairly unique situation, I have never needed to this before anyways.  I have a Linq query that returns data from a database using EF4.1.  I want to create multiple similar (same signature) anonymous (or even named if necessary) results from each query result.

Here's the code i'm using now:

```
var data = getMyData().Select(x => 
              new 
              {
                GoalName = x.GoalType.Name, 
                Start = x.StartDate, 
                End = x.EndDate, 
                x.StartValue, 
                x.CheckIns
              }).ToList();

var r1 = data.Select(x => 
              new 
              { 
                title = x.GoalName, 
                start = x.Start.ToString(), 
                end = x.End.ToString(), 
                className = "hidden", 
                type = "goal"
              });

var r2 = data.Select(x => 
              new 
              { 
                title = string.Format("Start: {0:0.##}", x.StartValue), 
                start = x.Start.ToString(), 
                end = x.Start.ToString(), 
                className = "", 
                type = "" 
              });

var r3 = data.Select(x => 
              new 
              { 
                title = "End", 
                start = x.End.ToString(), 
                end = x.End.ToString(), 
                className = "", 
                type = "" 
              });

var r4 = data.SelectMany(x => x.CheckIns)
           .Select(y => 
              new 
              { 
                title = y.CheckInValue.Value.ToString(), 
                start = y.CheckInDateTime.ToString(), 
                end = y.CheckInDateTime.ToString(), 
                className = "", 
                type = "" 
              });

var result = r1.Union(r2).Union(r3).Union(r4);
```

Now maybe this is as good a way as any, but I can't help feeling that i'm missing something.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You might want to reformat the code to be easier to read for those willing to help you.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you are trying to get returned?

Comment: @Chris Pietschmann - the code already was formatted, it just didn't have spaces between lines.  I guess that's a personal preference.  In any event, it's pretty obvious from looking at the code what I get back, and the code works fine.  I'm just looking for something that does exactly the same thing, but more efficient.

Comment: Do you need to do all those `ToString()` operations each time or could you pull them out and have `DateTime` values in the anonymous types instead and call ToString() only when you consume these results.

Comment: Why are you using `Union` instead of `Concat`?  It looks like you want to simply concatenate these not calculate the set union of them (which involves comparing them against each other for equality), right?

Comment: @Hightechrider - good point, Concat would be a better choice.  There won't be duplicates.  I need to do ToString because i'm returning the result as a JsonResult and for some reason the json it creates uses a numeric conversion, which seems to confuse the javascript that consumes it.

Comment: My point on the ToString() was that you don't need to do it in so many places: you can either do it in the first Select, or you can add a another Select at the end that does it.

Comment: @Hightechrider - Good catch.  Yes, I could probably do the .ToString in the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is actually OK I think.

But StevenzNPaul's suggestion not that bad, here's how you can use the `let` keyword to store the different projections, then select the results individually (for brevity, I did not project all the fields, but you get the point):

```
var query = from x in data
            let result1 = new {title = x.GoalName, start = x.Start}
            let result2 = new {title = string.Format("Start: {0:0.##}", x.StartValue), start = x.Start}
            let result3 = new {title = "End", start = x.End}
            let checkins = x.CheckIns.Select(checkin => new { title = "...", start = checkin.Start })
            from result in new[] { result1, result2, result3 }.Concat(checkins)
            select result;
```

Obviously, whether this is better is a matter of preference. Also, this will result in a different ordering, which may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I see what you mean. This code looks like it would likely result in several extra objects being created as well as more Selects.  In any case, an interesting solution.

Comment: I don't think it creates more objects. The main difference is that with this solution you loop over the input list (`data`) only once. The extra Selects just add more weight to 'the body of the for loop'.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an iterator using `yield` which also has the advantage of being evaluated lazily (doesn't require the ToList()). I created a typed class `Result` to hold the query results

```
private IEnumerable<Result> PerformQuery()
{
    var results= getMyData().Select(x => new {GoalName = x.GoalType.Name, 
   Start = x.StartDate, End = x.EndDate, x.StartValue, x.CheckIns});

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
          yield return new Result() { Title = result.GoalName, Start = result.Start.ToString(), End = result.End.ToString(), ClassName = "Hidden", Type = "Goal" };

          yield return new Result() { Title = String.Format("Start: {0:0.##}",result.StartValue), Start = result.Start.ToString(), End = result.Start.ToString() }

          yield return new Result() { Title = "End", Start = result.End.ToString(), End = result.End.ToString() };

          foreach (var checkIn in result.CheckIns)
               yield return new Result() { Title = checkIn.CheckInValue.Value.ToString(), Start = checkIn.CheckInDateTime.ToString(), End = checkIn.CheckInDateTime.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting approach, but seems less to add an additional layer of abstraction and thus slightly slower.

Answer (score 1):

try using let keyword it will work for you.

Comment: Let does not do what I need.  Let allows you to use several queries to make one query.  I want the reverse, one query with several result sets projected back into a single result.